# ADX studio registration

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, adxstudio-portals

We are hosting multiple portals using ADX studio in our CRM environment. One of the portal is using Contacts entity for user registration and other portal need to use Account entity for registration. All the documentation points to contacts entity. Can you please guide me how to use Account entity for user registration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Adx, but I think it's not possible to associate accounts to portal users. When you deploy the AdxStudio solution into CRM, it will create a number of fields in the Contact entity to store the required information for the authentication. Those fields don't exist in the Account entity and that's why I think that you can't use this entity. You can see the differences between the two entities in the following screenshot that I just took:
[image: adx]

**UPDATE**:

I've found this in Adx documentation:

> In an Adxstudio Portals application, an authenticated portal user is
> associated with either a **CRM Contact or System User**. The default
> Adxstudio Portals configuration is Contact-based, so we will use
> Contact as our example for the purposes of explaining security.

[More...](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/portal-authentication/)